# Как создать Сцену для SFML и передать обработку событий на ее элементы

Tags: c++, gui, события, sfml

Не могу понять как правильно составить зависимости между классами. Написал уже несколько элементов (Кнопка, Панель, Текстовое поле...). Но не понятно как вешать на них события, т.е. надо писать собственный EventHandler? Если да, то как его делать. Хотелось бы чтобы эти "события" на элементы вешались через конкретную реализацию сцены. Вот примерно как будет выглядеть абстрактная сцена:

```
namespace gui
{
class Menu : sf::Drawable
{
    protected:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const = 0;

    std::stack<sf::Drawable*> elements;

    public:
    virtual Menu();

    virtual ~Menu() = 0;

    virtual void initMenu() = 0;

    private:
};
}
```

И конкретное меню:

```
namespace gui
{

class StartMenu : gui::Menu
{
private:
        std::map<sf::Font, std::string> _fonts;
        std::map<sf::Texture,std::string> _textures;
        bool _prepared = false;

    bool loadFonts();
    bool loadTextures();

public:

    void bind(sf::Drawable*);
    void unbind(sf::Drawable*);

virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const;

StartMenu();
StartMenu(sf::RenderTarget &target);

void initMenu();

    void renderMenu();
    void holdMenu();

~StartMenu();
};

}
```

Как передать конкретное действие на нажатия/навод мышки к конкретному элементу через меню?

Comment: А что конкретно тут подразумевается под "событием"? Именно клавиатурный / мышиный ввод или обработку действия при активации элемента меню? Вообще события обычно подразумевают наличие нескольких сущностей - источник, тракт (механизм оповещения), фильтр и обработчик.

Comment: Да, мышиный ввод. Т.е. допустим при нажатии на элемент меню, оно перестает прорисовываться и заменяется на другую сцену. Хочется чтобы можно было повесить действие на элементы из сцены, в которой они находятся

Comment: В любом случае нужны два набора событий - собственно для событий мыши - курсор вошел в область окна / переместился / вышел / кнопки нажаты / отпущены, и для меню - выполнить пункт. Виждет меню будет переваривать события мыши и запускать события выполнения пункта меню.

Comment: @VTT Ага, а события нужно поверх всего писать, чтобы каждый класс имел  доступ к ним? Не могу найти примеров по событиям и их использовании в проекте.

Comment: События можно реализовать по-разному. Например сделать один абстрактный класс для всех событий мыши и наследовать меню от него, а другой для событий меню и наследовать обработчики меню от него. А можно делать отдельный абстрактный класс на каждое событие. А можно обойтись и вообще без явных абстрактных классов и принимать в качестве обработчиков событий обертку вроде `std::function`. Примеры можно найти в любом GUI фреймворке, например в QT или XAML (UWP).